# Intermittent "Unknown authorization header" 401 from GData

Tags: google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

As of 22:00 UTC yesterday (2013-11-15) our servers suddenly started getting "Unknown authorization header" failures when connecting to Google Calendar API (V2) via OAuth.

The problem seems completely intermittent. Right now we retry after each failure twice (with a four second delay each time) and approximately 10% of these retries succeed.

I saw on [this page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/oauth2-dev) that Google engineers monitor this tag on stackoverflow. If that is you - please help! My service is suffering and our customers are losing business. Please help me convince them they were right to bet on us and Google Calendar!

Comment: Update on this: we had side issue that was preventing the retry from working as effectively as it could. Having fixed that, we are now seeing nearly all connections succeed, but only after we try them up to three times. Could it be dependent on which machine at Google we are lucky enough to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get in touch with a Google SRE.  They have since diagnosed the issue and they are pushing a fix now.  Should be fixed sometime in the next few hours, I'm told.

Comment: Thanks very much for this update. Encouraging to hear that messages can get through - even indirectly. We are still seeing the effect on our servers, but hopefully this will tail off as their fix continues to roll out.

Answer (score 0):

The fix has been pushed and I just did a test confirming everything is working fine now.  Hopefully you are good to go as well.

Comment: Looks like there are still problems (or related problems?) being reported since Dec '13.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551974/gdata-unknown-authorization-header-started-12-11-13