# gdata Unknown authorization header - started 12/11/13

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

The google calendar sync had been working fine for a long time now suddenly starting yesterday we started getting the following error. I saw that this has happened in the past and google engineers (SRE) had to apply a patch to fix this.

com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unknown authorization header

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, I believe. We using the gdata Java libraries, and with logging enabled I see we send an AuthSub Authorization header when we call getFeed, but the 401 comes back asking for `WWW-Authenticate: GoogleLogin realm="https://accounts.google.com//ClientLogin"`. In case that's a clue for anyone. We do not see this problem accessing the ContactsService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Account Authentication APIs (**ClientLogin, AuthSub and OAuth 1.0**) are deprecated as per deprecation policy.
http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html

> Important: AuthSub has been officially deprecated as of April 20,
>   2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

Comment: I knew they were deprecated and we had planned a transition. I didnt expect to wake up one day and scramble to convert over

Answer (score 2):

We see this too using authsub authentication which says it will be supported until 2015 - started with the Google update that went out around Dec 10th

Comment: We were hoping the deprecated API would not stop working overnight.